# I want to edit the exe which is built in fox pro technology

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have one software which is built in foxpro technology, I don't have the source code of the project so I am using refox tools and trying to rebuild the exe with my modification. Does anyone have the idea how to get it done.

Comment: May I ask you if you are the author of the project? If you were, probably you already would know how to build as an executable so I suspect this is an act for pirating. Sorry if it is not.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing as Cetin.  Do you have VFP? If so, what version?  Have you ever programmed in VFP?  Do you have the rights to decompile and modify this program? Finally, have you contacted the original developer of the software to see if they are willing to make the necessary modifications you are seeking?  I get contacted by my clients all the time and asked if I can make such and such a change.

Comment: It's more likely to be some piece of legacy software, however it's far too broad a question.

Comment: Since most of the files on vfp are not treated as binary its kinda tricky to de compile a vfp exe.
Do your Best to contact the author or find de source code, otherwise you will be loosing a lot of time and maybe it would be better to build something From scratch.